# Google login: How to add query to callback-url?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm using PHP and the Google API client for PHP.
When a visitor is on my signup-page, there's a query string that contains information about what they're signing up for. So the url would be something like:      https://www.example.com/register/user?signupfor=research

I've recently added a button for registering through Google, and I was wondering if there's any way to add this same query to the callback/redirect url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out some different things, I've found a way.

The Google API Client has a function setState() that can be used to set any data in a unique string. Google adds this state to the url when redirecting back to your site.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

So you can just encode the array of params you want to pass in a json-object, use setState($params) and then get the state on your callback page and decode the json-object again.

Before redirecting to Google:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 ...
 $params = array(
  'signupfor' => 'research',
  ...
 );

 $client->setState(json_encode($params));
```

On my callback page:

```
$params = json_decode($_GET['state']);
```

And then I can whatever I want with my params-array.